# FusionAuth oAuth not working with TestCafe

Tags: testing, automation, automated-tests, e2e-testing, testcafe

I am failing to correctly login through the UI with the testing framework TestCafe. Our company uses FusionAuth for authentication which lives on a separate Domain from the application I am looking to test. At the moment im just trying to develop a Proof of Concept with logging in through the UI.

Currently, the cookie that I often see get set when logging in normal through my browser does not get set when going through testcafe. Thus when you return to the application it does not to know that you are authenticated.

It seems that the passing of cookies / local storage from the IDP login page back to the Application in test does not happen.

Ive tried useing Role's with preserveUrl set to true.

```
const testUser = Role('{domainURL}/login', async t => {
    const username = 'username'; //Not real values
    const password = 'passwword';
    await t
        .typeText('#loginId', username)
        .typeText('#password', password)
        .click('.submit');
}, { preserveUrl: true });

test
    .disablePageCaching('Login to Test Users Account', async t => {

        await t.useRole(testUser);

    });
```

Ive also tried just using selectors and putting in the Credientials manually in the UI. Neither have worked so far for me.

I was curious if:

1. I am approaching this wrong?
2. What is the best approach for Black box End-2-End Testing with testcafe when dealing with login?

I know this is probably not the best place, but i wasn't sure how else to contact testcafe support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was turned into a github Issue ticket that can be found [here](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/6408). Going to close this Question for now.

Answer (score 2):

In general, TestCafe Roles is the recommended approach for dealing with logging. There can be some FusionAuth specifics that do not work correctly with TestCafe. If you want our TestCafe team to research this issue, you can create an issue in our github repository using the following link: https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe/issues/new?assignees=&labels=&template=bug-report.md

Please note that we will need an example that demonstrates the issue. If you cannot share your project/login/password publicly, you can send it to support@devexpress.com.

Comment: Thanks for following up. I'll probably do that once I finish trying some other solutions. Thank you!